# Chrome remote desktop AND android emulator

Tags: android-studio, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I remote(chrome remote) to my desktop which runs android studio. When I try to run the emulator from android studio, i see the window with the virtual device open. But the device doesn't power on. This is not the behavior when I use the desktop directly to run the android project. Could this behavior be because of the remoting? If so how do i change it?

My need is to work on android studio on a remote connection, if there is a way to achieve it, kindly advise.

This is the AVD log

```
    C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none

emulator: device fd:1228

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode

creating window 61 83 462 820
```

logcat

```
    04-29 12:06:39.077    1966-1966/com.example.xxx.four4 E/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10053: Read-only file system
04-29 12:06:39.077    1966-1966/com.example.xxx.four4 W/Zygote﹕ createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
04-29 12:06:39.078    1966-1966/com.example.xxx.four4 I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-29 12:06:39.183    1966-1986/com.example.xxx.four4 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
04-29 12:06:39.186    1966-1966/com.example.xxx.four4 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa607f4c0, tid 1966
04-29 12:06:39.319    1966-1966/com.example.xxx.four4 D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
04-29 12:06:40.050    1966-1966/com.example.xxx.four4 I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-29 12:06:40.184    1966-1986/com.example.xxx.four4 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa607fa60, tid 1986
04-29 12:06:40.231    1966-1986/com.example.xxx.four4 I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-29 12:06:40.469    1966-1986/com.example.xxx.four4 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-29 12:06:40.521    1966-1986/com.example.xxx.four4 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-29 12:06:40.521    1966-1986/com.example.xxx.four4 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6083580, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-29 12:07:12.637    1966-1973/com.example.xxx.four4 W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 13.570ms
```

Thanks.

Comment: I experience the same issue when using Windows RDP to get into my remote workstation.  However, it only seems to happen when I run an x86 or x86_64 image.  ARM images run fine.  So for now I've been living with the slower emulation when working remotely.  Just curious if it's the same in your environment, and if so, perhaps it's an interim solution for ya.  But have you found a proper fix yet?

Comment: @s.co.tt Thanks for the workaround. I did not try getting a fix after the initial failures. Will check with the ARM image and let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue using a remote desktop. I solved it using another remote access application TeamViewer (http://teamviewer.com)
Using TeamViewer you can run any Android Emulator like x86, x86_64 or arm.

Answer (score -1):

The Android emulator is not using all of your cpu capabilities but rather a single thread and my guess is that the remote desktop and the emulator are sharing the same thread thus preventing from your emulator to run while using the remote desktop. the solution is to use a stronger cpu or a different remote desktop as user2839592 said.

Comment: It's actually an issue related to initializing OpenGL over RDP